# Network Link Conditioner for Xcode 8.1 not responding

Tags: ios, networking, ios-simulator, xcode8, developer-tools

I downloaded the `Additional Tools for Xcode 8.1` and installed the `Network Link Conditioner` tool it contains, and when I open its preferences pane and try to switch it ON, I always get an `Application Not Responding` and I have to force quit.

I have unlocked changes in the pane, and I am using `Xcode 8.1` and `macOS Sierra 10.12.1`. Is someone else experiencing this?